# How do I make useEffect run in order?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

My goal is to fetch my API and do some logic with the data when the component mounts. I created another useEffect to only run when the first the fetch calls are successful. I am able to get all my data, but I am getting the error "cannot read property 'length' of null". If I understood correctly, the second useEffect will run whenever companyData changes.

Error:

```
 54 | useEffect(() => {
  55 |   async function organizeReviews() {
  56 |     let companyReviews = []
> 57 |       for(let i = 0; i < companyData.length; i++) {
     | ^  58 |         let reviewsForThisCo = []
  59 |         // loop through userReviews array
  60 |         for(let j=0; j < userReviews.length; j++) {
```

Code:

```
  const [averageRatings, setAverageRatings] = useState(null)
  const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState(null)
  const [userReviews, setUserReviews] = useState([])
  const [organizedReviews, setOrganizedReviews] = useState(null)

  // Adding empty [] as second argument to run once component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getRatings() {
      try{
        const ratingRes = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/v1/collected_reviews/')
        const ratingJson = await ratingRes.json()
        setAverageRatings(ratingJson.data)
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    async function getCompanyData() {
      try{
        const companyDataRes = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/v1/companies/')
        const companyDataJson = await companyDataRes.json()
        setCompanyData(companyDataJson.data)
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    async function getCompanyReviews() {
      try{
        const reviewsRes = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/v1/reviews/')
        const reviewsJson = await reviewsRes.json()
        setUserReviews(reviewsJson.data)
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    getRatings()
    getCompanyData()
    getCompanyReviews()

  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function organizeReviews() {
      let companyReviews = []
        for(let i = 0; i < companyData.length; i++) {
          let reviewsForThisCo = []
          // loop through userReviews array
          for(let j=0; j < userReviews.length; j++) {
            // if the user review id matches the company id
            if(userReviews[j].company.id === companyData[i].id) {
              reviewsForThisCo.push(userReviews[j])
            }
          }
            companyReviews.push(reviewsForThisCo)
        }
        setOrganizedReviews(companyReviews)
    }
    organizeReviews()
  }, [companyData])
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` inside the `companyData` useEffect? I think you'll find that it is being fired when set to `null` on mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the second useEffect will run whenever companyData changes.

That's true.  But it will also always run on initial mount of the component. So you've got to make sure that your `companyData` exists inside your second `useEffect`, as it won't exist on first render:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    if (companyData){
      async function organizeReviews() {
        let companyReviews = []
          for(let i = 0; i < companyData.length; i++) {
            let reviewsForThisCo = []
            // loop through userReviews array
            for(let j=0; j < userReviews.length; j++) {
              // if the user review id matches the company id
              if(userReviews[j].company.id === companyData[i].id) {
                reviewsForThisCo.push(userReviews[j])
              }
            }
              companyReviews.push(reviewsForThisCo)
          }
          setOrganizedReviews(companyReviews)
      }
      organizeReviews()
    } // if (companyData)

  }, [companyData])
```

Now it will run on first render, but do nothing, as `companyData` doesn't exist yet.  Then it will run every time `companyData` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the useRef() in second useEffect like below

```
    const mounted = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
      if (!mounted.current) {
        mounted.current = true;
      } else {
        async function organizeReviews() {
      let companyReviews = []
        for(let i = 0; i < companyData.length; i++) {
          let reviewsForThisCo = []
          // loop through userReviews array
          for(let j=0; j < userReviews.length; j++) {
            // if the user review id matches the company id
            if(userReviews[j].company.id === companyData[i].id) {
              reviewsForThisCo.push(userReviews[j])
            }
          }
            companyReviews.push(reviewsForThisCo)
        }
        setOrganizedReviews(companyReviews)
    }
    organizeReviews()
}
      }, [companyData])
```

Comment: By adding useRef() we are making sure that on component mount we only set the mount.current=true and on component update we are calling the organizeReviews() function

Answer (score 0):

> If I understood correctly, the second useEffect will run whenever companyData changes.

yes but when the second useEffect tries to apply the .length to "companyData" this is still null, and you can not apply .length to a null variable. this error stops the execution before "companyData" changes

what you have to do is to initialize "companyData" as a empty array

```js
const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState([])
```

This is the easier way, or you can review inside the second useEffect is "companyData" exists

```js
useEffect(() => {
async function organizeReviews() {
  let companyReviews = []
    for(let i = 0; i < companyData.length; i++) {
      let reviewsForThisCo = []
      // loop through userReviews array
      for(let j=0; j < userReviews.length; j++) {
        // if the user review id matches the company id
        if(userReviews[j].company.id === companyData[i].id) {
          reviewsForThisCo.push(userReviews[j])
        }
      }
        companyReviews.push(reviewsForThisCo)
    }
    setOrganizedReviews(companyReviews)
}
if (companyData)
organizeReviews()
  }, [companyData])
```